# How can discord bots have a mobile status?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've seen multiple Discord bots using a mobile online presence. I have tried to find some more information about this but couldn't find anything especially through the Discord.py documentation. Would this happen to mean this is not included in the Discord.py library?

Would this be breaking the Discord API or guidelines as it seems they have intentionally left out the mobile presence?

Comment: They can't. Not officially anyways since discord API doesnt expose this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it is working in JS but it needs some modifications in code like this you have to dig a little in python to get like this.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Client = new Discord.Client()
const Constants = require('discord.js/src/util/Constants.js')
Constants.DefaultOptions.ws.properties.$browser = `Discord iOS`
Client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Loading status..")
  Client.user.setActivity(`!help for commands`, { type: 3, browser: "DISCORD IOS"  });
});
```